# i want to change 2 images onmouseover again and agian

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover

I want to change 2 pictures while mouseover. #E.G. once i will mouseover the image will change...it will not change until I mouseover again. how can I do it. Here's my code

```js
function updatePic(){
    if(document.getElementById("dpic").src == "images/h1.jpg"){
        document.getElementById("dpic").src = "images/h.jpg";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("dpic").src == "images/h.jpg"){
        document.getElementById("dpic").src = "images/h1.jpg";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:** I think **onmouseenter** is the mouse event that you're looking for:

```js
function change() {
  
var current = document.getElementById("image").getAttribute("src");
  
if (current == "http://i.imgur.com/HNj6tRD.jpg") {    
document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", "http://i.imgur.com/3jxqrKP.jpg");
} else {
document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", "http://i.imgur.com/HNj6tRD.jpg");
}    
}
```

```css
#image {
width:550px;
height:150px;
position:relative;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" alt=image src="http://i.imgur.com/HNj6tRD.jpg" onmouseenter="change()">
```

Comment: I can create a function for onmouseout if I wanna make this...suppose image1 is the main image...onmouseover it will change to image2...and image1 will come when I mouseover again

Comment: Updated. Check it again, please.

Comment: i don't want to change the background image...i want to change image source...

`<img id="dpic" src="images/h.JPG" width="150px" height="150px" onmouseover="updatePic();">`

Answer (score 0):

J.Hasan, there are easier ways. Can you set one of the images as a background image to a div?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        div {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background: url(image1.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size:100% 100%;
            }
        img {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            opacity:0;
            }
        img:hover {opacity:1;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="image2.jpg">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If it's a slideshow you want, try this. The beauty of this slideshow is that it does not load all the images when the page loads. Just make a white image (img0.jpg) to set the size of the slideshow in the "slideshowWrap" div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="_/js/slides.js"></script>
        <script>
        function showSlides(){
            // SETTINGS
            var rotation = 5000; // set rotation speed (milliseconds)
            var transition = 1000; // set transition speed (milliseconds)
            var path = "_/images/banners/"; // the path to the slides (images)
            // SLIDES
            var slides = [ // add slides (images) to the slideshow (no comma after last slide)
                "img1.jpg",
                "img2.jpg",
                "img3.jpg",
                "img4.jpg"
                ];

        // SLIDESHOW

            var slideAmt = slides.length -1;
            slideTrn ++;
            slideTrn = (slideTrn > 2)?1:slideTrn;

            if(firstSlide == true){
                // slideCnt = 0
                slideCnt ++;
                $("#slide1").attr("src", path + slides[slideCnt]); // slide 0
                $("#slide1").css({"z-index":"1","opacity":"1"});
                slideCnt ++;
                slideCnt = (slideCnt > slideAmt)?0:slideCnt;
                $("#slide2").attr("src", path + slides[slideCnt]); // slide 1
                $("#slide2").css({"z-index":"2",});
                firstSlide = false;
                }
            else{
                if(slideTrn == 2){
                    // slideCnt = 1
                    $("#slide2").animate({opacity:"1"}, transition, function(){ // slide 1 fades in
                        $("#slide1").css({"opacity":"0"}); // slide 0
                        $("#slide2").css({"z-index":"1"}); // slide 1
                        $("#slide1").css({"z-index":"2"});
                        slideCnt ++;
                        slideCnt = (slideCnt > slideAmt)?0:slideCnt;
                        $("#slide1").attr("src", path + slides[slideCnt]); // slide 2
                        });
                    }
                else{
                    // slideCnt = 2
                    $("#slide1").animate({opacity:"1"}, transition, function(){
                        $("#slide2").css({"opacity":"0"});
                        $("#slide1").css({"z-index":"1"});
                        $("#slide2").css({"z-index":"2"});
                        slideCnt ++;
                        slideCnt = (slideCnt > slideAmt)?0:slideCnt;
                        $("#slide2").attr("src", path + slides[slideCnt]);
                        });
                    }
                }
            var t = setTimeout(showSlides, rotation);
            }

        function setValues(){
            firstSlide = true;
            slideCnt = -1;
            slideTrn = 0;
            manSlide = 0;
            }

        window.addEventListener("load", setValues);
        window.addEventListener("load", showSlides);
        </script>
        <style>
        #slideshowWrap {
            width:100%;
            min-height:1px;
            overflow:auto;
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slideshowWrap" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;">
            <img alt="" class="blank" src="img0.jpg"> <!-- set white image just to set the size of div "slideshowWrap" -->
            <img alt="" class="slide" src="_/" id="slide1">
            <img alt="" class="slide" src="_/" id="slide2">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's kind of a gallery thing

Answer (score 0):

The may well be a more efficient way but if you just want it to work try your JS like this.

```
    var x = 0;
function rollOver() {
    var image1 = "url(images/RIOBtn1.gif)";
    var image2 = "url(images/RIO2Rollover.gif)";
    var image3 = "url(images/RIO1Rollover.gif)";
    var array11 = [image1,image2,image3];

    if (x == 0){
        document.getElementById("myButton").style.backgroundImage = array11[x];
        x++;
    } else if (x == 1) {
        document.getElementById("myButton").style.backgroundImage = array11[x];
        x++;
    } else if (x == 2) {
        document.getElementById("myButton").style.backgroundImage = array11[x];
        x = 0;
    }
    }
```

All this does is puts the url's into an array and will continue to loop through them. I done this as a quick so it is a little messy. 
In the HTML it is just:

```
<button id="myButton" onmouseover="rollOver()"></button>
```

EDIT ***********************************

As you want the src to change, the code is almost the same but changing the source.

```
    var x = 0;
function rollOver() {
    var image1 = "images/RIOBtn1.gif";
    var image2 = "images/RIO2Rollover.gif";
    var image3 = "images/RIO1Rollover.gif";
    var array11 = [image1,image2,image3];

    if (x == 0){
        document.getElementById("myButton").src = array11[x];
        x++;
    } else if (x == 1) {
        document.getElementById("myButton").src = array11[x];
        x++;
    } else if (x == 2) {
        document.getElementById("myButton").src = array11[x];
        x = 0;
    }
    }

    <img src="images/HomeBtn1.gif" id="myButton" onmouseover="rollOver()">
```

Comment: my html code where i want to change the image <br>
`<img id="dpic" src="images/h.JPG" width="150px" height="150px" onmouseover="updatePic();">`

Comment: After modifying your code I'm succeeded. It solved my  problem.

Comment: `var x =0;
function updatePic(){


    var img1 = "images/h1.jpg";
    var img2 = "images/h.jpg";
    var array11 = [img1,img2];

    if(x == 0){
        document.getElementById("dpic").src = array11[x];
        x++;
    }
    else if (x==1){
        document.getElementById("dpic").src = array11[x];
        x = 0;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var strImgSrc1 = "http://virtualrailfan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/200_200_sample.jpg";
    var strImgSrc2 = "http://www.eminenstore.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/samples.jpg";
    $("img").mouseover(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("src") === strImgSrc1)
        {
            $(this).attr("src", strImgSrc2);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).attr("src", strImgSrc1);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img border="1" src="http://www.eminenstore.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/samples.jpg" height="300" width="300"/>
```